# Pivot Table ineffectively capturing Multiple Selection Data Validated Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, data-validation

I have created a tracker which has several columns that allow multiple selection of values via data validation.

The goal is to create dashboards with slicers to analyse this data. For eg- Lets assume I would like to see all the clients that fall under a Jt. Dev Agreement.
When I run a pivot I am unable to get independent entries for the same. It gets clubbed along with the other values(Financing opportunity) selected as multiple items.

Please help with a solution wherein the pivot can capture these entries independently without getting clubbed.
So it doesn't affect my dashboard analysis.

[image: Pivot Table not capturing separate entries for the multiple values selected in data validated cells]

Comment: This question is likely to be voted down, or even closed, unles you [edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1416266/edit) to start adding details: what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, how does it fail to meet the required goal? etc.

Comment: what exactly do you want to know

Comment: I have edited the post with some more details, hope I am able to convey the issue now.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the pivot table layout to tabular view and turn off the subtotals and grand totals.
Then use the 'Sr. No' column as the top item in the rows area. This gives the pivot a table a unique value to show all of the other values by.
After the unique field is added the others can be added in any order.

[Click here for sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTAp1.png)